# In which book does Tordek mention a "+3 weapon"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification

I recall a D&D 3.5e (or maybe 3e) book in which a fighter (probably Tordek the dwarf) talks in-character about "a +3 weapon," most likely a sword or an axe. This would have been in one of those color quotes they like to put at the beginning of a chapter.

(Knowing where this is from would help me refine [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63593/4173).)

Comment: As someone who considers myself a reasonably well-informed close voter, how is this too broad? Is there a whole bunch of books where fighters talk in character about +3 weapons?

Comment: @Miniman There is almost no detail: we don’t have the actual statement, we don’t even know what edition it might have been in, and it’s almost a miracle that burlap happened to know it.

Comment: I know it's not the best answer, and I wouldn't have asked it if someone didn't sugges me to, and I'm sorry for the wild goose chase but hey, this is not what too broad is for. It's probably just a question to be left unvoted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Magic Item Compendium*, p. 5:

> "My armor? +3 adamantine light fortification full plate. I wouldn't leave home without it."
>
> —Tordek

Quite specific. Neither an axe nor a sword though.

Comment: Of course, that's why all this looking for weapons didn't bear (or beard, since we're talking about dwarves) any result.

Comment: I was actually interested in the "original" question too, I couldn't remember the quote, just checked the usual suspects with chapters on items/magic items (PHB, PHB2, DMG, Complete Warrior and finally MIC). "+3" or "light fortification" is already a simplification over "enchanted to provide +3 enhancement bonus" or "strong abjuration providing 25% chance for normal damage in case of sneak attach or critical hit".