# Alternate raw break DC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, house-rules

Due to events that occurred during my games I had to come up with a DC to break a door. The DMG has some details on this but its max DC was 28 vs str check on an iron door. After doing the normal made up DC the player still got through this door (an adamantine door 2 inch thick and yes it fit the area)

This got me thinking that the table based DC was in a sense... not complete. So I came up with a mathematical check and rebalance of the DC.

New check
10+hardness+4/in thick

This makes a 2 inch thick adamantine door a DC 38.

Mind you this is literally to break the door not just pop it open.

Was wondering what others would think on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Epic Obstacles](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/obstacles.htm) (and I presume the *Epic Level Handbook* itself, but that sits at the bottom of a box) gives the break DC of an 3" thick adamantine door as 66, so I'd say 38 is much too low, even for a 2" door.

However... I think your real problem here is the same as in [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64852/power-player-is-a-problem-any-fix): you're letting the players dictate what should happen. If you don't want the door to break, let them roll the die and just say "Nothing happens, other than your shoulder hurts a lot". This may depend a bit on your social contract and the like.

Comment: You have a good point and I was unaware that information existed. Perhaps I could have avoided the whole thing haha.

Comment: Since you brought it up. This was actually one of the events I spoke about already. Not a new one. Locked door the rogue didn't get on try 1. He kicked it in.